# asciidoc remove indent after full stop ":"

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

asciidoc

```
= Test

palim::
Blablablub

palim:

* Bla
* Blub

palimpalim::
Blablablub
```

pdf output.

[image]

**How can I remove the indentation for `palimpalim`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your markup, the second `palim` definition only has one colon instead of two, so Asciidoctor is interpreting the `palimpalim` term as part of the definition for the initial `palim` term.